# sklearn: create sparse feature vector from multiple choice features

Tags: scikit-learn

I have data which looks like this:

```
20003.0, 20003.1, 20004.0, 20004.1, 34
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Where the columns with ending .* are multiple choice and the values they take on are categorical.

Ideally, I would be able to pass `[{'20003': ['1', '2'], '20004': ['3', '4'], '34': 5}]` to `DictVectorizer` but this is not supported yet.

How should this data be loaded to create sparse feature vectors?

Comment: what is your data? is it text, DataFrame, array, something else?

Comment: It is a DataFrame read from CSV.

Comment: can you sum up the values in similar columns? For example: `[{'20003': 3, '20004': 7, '34': 5}]` - this can be easily passed to DictVectorizer

Answer (score 0):

If you can sum up you the values for the same groups of columns:

```
In [63]: df
Out[63]:
   20003.0  20003.1  20004.0  20004.1  34
0        1        2        3        4   5

In [64]: d = df.groupby(df.columns.str.split('.').str[0], axis=1).sum().to_dict('r')

In [65]: d
Out[65]: [{'20003': 3, '20004': 7, '34': 5}]

In [66]: from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer

In [67]: v = DictVectorizer()

In [68]: X = v.fit_transform(d)

In [69]: X.toarray()
Out[69]: array([[ 3.,  7.,  5.]])

In [70]: v.inverse_transform(X)
Out[70]: [{'20003': 3.0, '20004': 7.0, '34': 5.0}]
```

Explanation:

```
In [71]: df.groupby(df.columns.str.split('.').str[0], axis=1).sum()
Out[71]:
   20003  20004  34
0      3      7   5

In [72]: df.groupby(df.columns.str.split('.').str[0], axis=1).sum().to_dict('r')
Out[72]: [{'20003': 3, '20004': 7, '34': 5}]
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot sum up those values. What may be unclear is that they are categorical.